# Excel/VBA code ignores inputted arguments

Tags: excel, vba, vbe

I have a VBA sub that should load in user code modules when needed.
My issue is that when I pass ("ModuleA",".bas") the code will return "ModuleB". ModuleB does not exist (was deleted) within the filepath specified.

How can this code return a non-existing file when it is specifically passed a different value? The 'filepath' variable contains the correct path and it is being correctly being passed to the import statement.

Furthermore, the "Remove" statement does not remove the module passed to it.

I've never run into an issue like this and am lost on what to do.

What I have tried: Restarting excel/PC, renaming modules to change path, adding code to delete modules at end of sub.

```
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''SJH
'LoadModule
'
'Loads in a module with a specified name from the BigData Directory
'
'extension includes the ., so .frm or .bas
'
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Public Sub LoadModule(ByVal ModuleName As String, ByVal extension As String)
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    Err.Clear
     'handle errors in-line...
    On Error Resume Next

    'include reference to "Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility"
    Dim vbproj As VBIDE.VBProject
    Dim vbc As VBIDE.VBComponent
    Dim filepath As String

    filepath = ("\\uslafnas01\GE_LAB\BigData\" & ModuleName & extension)
    Set vbproj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject

    'Error will occur if component with this name is not in the project
    Set vbc = vbproj.VBComponents(ModuleName)

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        'so add it...
        vbproj.VBComponents.Import filepath
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
           MsgBox ("Could not import " & ModuleName & " Module: " & filepath)
        End If
    Else
        'no error - vbc should be valid object
        'remove existing version first before adding new version
        vbproj.VBComponents.Remove vbc
        vbproj.VBComponents.Import filepath
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            MsgBox ("New " & ModuleName & " couldn't replace old " & ModuleName & " Module " & filepath)
        End If
    End If


    'Set vbc = Nothing
    'Set vbproj = Nothing


End Sub
```

Comment: Try removing the `On Error Resume Next` statement and see what other errors you are getting. only do this when you expect an error on a line of code and then set back to `On Error Goto 0` after that line. Then let us know what is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of a module isn't determined by its file name, but by a hidden `VB_Name` attribute that you can see if you open the module in, say, Notepad.

If you open `ModuleA.bas` in Notepad, I suspect you'll see this as the very first line, above `Option Explicit`:

```
Attribute VB_Name = "ModuleB"
```

The file name is irrelevant, it's this attribute that determines the programmatic name of a VBA module.

Module & member attributes cannot be viewed or edited (directly) in the VBE.

Comment: Thanks, you got it!